# Leaflet Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geosearch' of undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter, leaflet

i want to make search fill and search button but i got this error in console Leaflet `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geosearch' of undefined`. i have include that has to but it doesn't work

i have include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.3.2/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css" integrity="sha512-IM3Hs+feyi40yZhDH6kV8vQMg4Fh20s9OzInIIAc4nx7aMYMfo+IenRUekoYsHZqGkREUgx0VvlEsgm7nCDW9g==" crossorigin="">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.3.2/dist/esri-leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-6LVib9wGnqVKIClCduEwsCub7iauLXpwrd5njR2J507m3A2a4HXJDLMiSZzjcksag3UluIfuW1KzuWVI5n/cuQ==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.3.2/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js" integrity="sha512-8twnXcrOGP3WfMvjB0jS5pNigFuIWj4ALwWEgxhZ+mxvjF5/FBPVd5uAxqT8dd2kUmTVK9+yQJ4CmTmSg/sXAQ==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

in the body i have put the container too

```
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

here is it the script code

```
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([5.5725508, 95.3447782], 16);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        maxZoom: 20,
        accessToken: 'faore342fdsf'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.control.scale().addTo(map);
    var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(map);`

https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/geocoding-control.html